# Counting is a combination of several skills, each _______ on the other

Tags: word-choice, verbs

*This question came in the Dhaka university admission exam 2015-16*

Q) Counting is a combination of several skills, each _______ on the other

(a) building

(b) reinforcing

(c) shaping

(d) improving

I think that the answer is probably (a). Question bank says the answer is (c). Which is the correct answer?

Comment: In Indian English,  is "shaping on" commonly used? What do any of the proposed solutions *really* mean where "counting skills" are concerned?

Comment: Did you copy the question precisely? I would think it should be "each one ..... on the other"

Comment: @Mari-LouA I checked again; I did copy the question correctly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't recall hearing "shaping on" from anyone ever. I have no idea what "counting skills" even mean. Probably, they are alluding to accounting, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: https://blog.learntube.academy/du-a-unit-admission-question-solution-2015-2016/#:~:text=Counting%20is%20a%20combination%20of%20several%20skills%2C%20each%20______%20on%20the%20other.

Comment: Great find, I suppose *each* is sufficient on its own, so "each one" is redundant. Guess what? **The answer supplied is indeed "building"**.  https://blog.learntube.academy/du-a-unit-admission-question-solution-2015-2016/#:~:text=Counting%20is%20a%20combination%20of%20several%20skills%2C%20each%20______%20on%20the%20other

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Yeah. My question bank can suck sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right.  You *build on* things.  I've never heard the expression *shaping on* and I don't think it's correct, either.  I would go a step further:  I'm familiar with the notion of *shaping things*.  It's the presence of the word *on* that I think is flat wrong.